# Cleaning a Field value in a SQL table based on a Lookup

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, lookup, fuzzy-search

I would like to clean up field values based on a Lookup  supplied by Client. Unfortunately Field has so many different combinations of names. E.g some clients names have combinations of "Limited" or "ltd". Some have missing spaces. What would be the best approach to cleanse this field based on a lookup supplied by Client.

[SQL Extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAK2D.png)

Comment: Can you make your question little more clear? Like adding a sample scenarios

Comment: I load monthly financial invoices in reporting databases using ETL packages and then i create reports based on this monthly data.Now client names in these files are all over the place. Each client will have so many different combinations of spelling.Just as an exmple, "Alliance Pharmaceutical Ltd", "Alliance Pharmaceuticals Ltd","Alliance Pharmaceutical Ltd".Alliance Pharmaceuticals Limited". Now these are the 3 different names for the same client. One with "S". One without "S". One with "ltd". One as limited.Now I have asked finance for a Lookup.is there an easy way in sql to clean this field

Comment: Maybe you should try something like a mapping table where you can map there abbreviations like Ltd and Ltd. are same as limited and so on. And then from that table, you can match it against the correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea is to use [RegEx approach](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/regex-efficient-sql-querying). The main idea is to create function in SQL Server that calls C# method in an assembly via SQL Server CLR. You have the entire code in the provided link.